# PHP file timestamp (change Attribut)

Tags: php, timestamp

I have some pictures in a folder and i rename them with PHP. Unfortunately the change Attribut is set to the current date and time. I just want to keep the original one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the rename command, get the file's existing modification time using the `filemtime()` function, like this: `$mtime = filemtime($file);`

Then, after the rename command, set the modification time back to that value using the `touch()` function, like this: `touch($file, $mtime, $mtime);`

Read more:

- [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)
- [touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php)